# Network communication between three computers using SSH

Tags: networking, command-line, ssh

Say I'm on computer A and I use SSH to get a console on computer B.  Then through this SSH console I copy files from computer B to computer C.

```
                                    ME (Computer A)
                                    |
                                    | (ssh to)

                                  Computer B       ---------->       Computer C
                                                  (copy files to)
```

What network traffic comes over the wire to me and my console and what traffic only moves between computer B and computer C?  Is my assumption that the copied files' data only moves between B & C and not A & B?

Comment: not a question, and yes, you'll probably want to redirect all output to of the copy/xcopy operations with `>/dev/null` to minimize every bit of bandwidth from console output to your terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. `B` and `C` have no knowledge of `A`. As far as `C` is concerned, a user from `B` is launching (I assume) an `scp` command and tranferring files from `C` to `B`. Whether that user has logged in from `A` or `Y`or `Z` is completely irrelevant. At that moment the user is on `B` and that is all that `C` will know.

So, any transfer between `B` and `C` is just that, a transfer between `B` and `C`, completely independent of `A`. The only exception transfer is of the few bytes of output displayed on your terminal. Those are the only things that are transferred back to `A` to be displayed on your screen. The actual *files* never touch `A`.